# How is "abort" implemented on platforms that does not support signals in C?

Tags: c, signals, abort, signal-handling

The `abort` function in C is supposed to raise a `SIGABRT` signal. But what if the underlying platform does not support the `SIGABRT` signal or does not support signals at all, for example, when C is ported to some non-Posix-compliant OSes. In this case, what should the implementer do?

Comment: It depends on the platform. `abort` probably should terminate the program one way or another.

Comment: If I needed to implement it, I would use setjmp/longjmp in the runtime startup code.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple, in fact. In that case, the implementer of the C runtime needs to make sure that `SIGABRT` is delivered to `signal`, without help from the OS. It's purely inside a single process.

Comment: what do you mean by "delivered to signal" if the OS does not support signals?

Comment: @JohnZ.Li Function `signal` is part of the C standard library. There is no support by the OS required by the C standard. If you raise a signal, the C library has all it needs to find the callback registered with `signal` function.